# Python 3 : import module from top level package

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, module, package

I have this simple package structure with one module called `ui`:

```sh
test/
├── app.py
├── __init__.py
└── ui
    ├── __init__.py
    └── window.py

1 directory, 4 files
```

The `window.py` file contains a basic class :

```py
# test/ui/window.py

class Window():
    def __init__(self):
        print("Window constructor")
```

and in my `app.py` I have :

```py
# test/app.py

from ui import window

def run():
    w = window.Window()
```

Now in a Python 3 shell, I should be able to import the module `app` from the package `test` call the run function like this (I am in the parent directory of the package) :

```py
>>> import test.app
>>> test.app.run()
```

However I get this error (with Python3) :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test/app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ui import window
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ui'
```

Note that this works with Python2.7...

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested in python 3.8

```
# test/app.py

from .ui import window


def run():
    w = window.Window()
```

```
>>> import test.app
>>> test.app.run()
Window constructor
```

You have to make a . infront of the ui to say that you are using a local folder.
Since i don't know much about python 2 in general, i can't explain to you why its working there, but my best guess is, that they changed how to do relative imports in python 3

Comment: Thanks, it works for both python 2.7 and python 3.8 actually with the relative import.